# Posix threads synchronization with mutexes

Tags: linux, multithreading

The more I try to learn this thing, the more I get confused, so I am open to any advice and help. Thanks. Program is about narrow bridge(mutex) and running cars(processes) on it, but only one process can cross it at one time. After crossing, a bridge thread can add itself to queue or go to the city where it sleeps and then add to queue. Processes(cars) need to run until program is terminated. If necessary I can translate code to english. After compilation run it like this: **./program -n -debug** 
n - number of threads, debug - printing queue, optional only. I think threads doesnt work synchronyzed, for example I runned program for 8 threads and had thread with number 34 in queue. No idea why, and it happened after I "fixed" code.

```
/*
There's a road(bridge) from city A to B. Only one car can use it to move at a time. 
Cars should run( change cities ) all the time, no end of program.
Access to the bridge should be synchronized with mutexes. Every car have its numer from 1 to N where N is given as first parameter.
Program should printing something like this when one of printing variable is changing:
A - 5 10 >> >[>> 4 >> ] << <4 6 - B
@up That means that in city A is 5 cars, in city A queue is 10 cars ( wanting to change city ). Thread with numer 4 is changing city from A to B. In city B queue is 4 cars and in city B is 6 cars.
If second parameter -debug is given, then program should printf queue status.   
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

pthread_mutex_t countOfQueueA;
pthread_mutex_t countOfQueueB; 
pthread_mutex_t bridge; 
pthread_mutex_t queueA; 
pthread_mutex_t queueB;
pthread_mutex_t cityA; 
pthread_mutex_t cityB; 

int inQueueA = 0; // Number of cars in queue of city A
int inQueueB = 0; // Number of cars in queue of city B
int inCityA = 0; // Number of cars in city A
int inCityB = 0; // Number of cars in city B

int createdThreads = 0; // Number of created threads by pthread_create
int numberOfCars = 0; // 
int debugMode = 0; // 0 - no, 1 - debug
int *queueInA; // Pointer to queue in city A
int *queueInB; // Pointer to queue in city B



void printQueue(char city)
{
    int i;
    if (city == 'a')
    {
    printf("\nQueue A status: ");
    for (i = 0; i<numberOfCars; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", queueInA[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
    else if (city == 'b')
    {
    printf("\nQueue B status: ");
    for (i = 0; i<numberOfCars; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", queueInB[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

void addToQueue(char city, int threadNumber) // Adding at the end of the queue in selected city
{
    if (city == 'a')
    {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queueA);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&countOfQueueA);
    int i = 0;
    while (queueInA[i] != 0) //Looking for first free place = 0 to add car
    {
        i++;
    }
    queueInA[i] = threadNumber;
    inQueueA++;
    printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [ BLANK  ] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, inQueueB, inCityB);
    if (debugMode == 1)
    {
        printQueue(city);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueA);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&countOfQueueA);
    }
    else if (city == 'b')
    {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queueB);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&countOfQueueB);
    int i = 0;
    while (queueInB[i] != 0) 
    {
        i++;
    }
    queueInB[i] = threadNumber;
    inQueueB++;
    printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [ BLANK  ] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, inQueueB, inCityB);
    if (debugMode == 1)
    {
        printQueue(city);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueB);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&countOfQueueB);
    }
}

void changeCity2(int threadNumber, char city)
{
    if (city == 'a')
    {
    while (queueInA[0] != threadNumber);// Oczekiwanie dopoki samochod nie jest 1szy w kolejce

    pthread_mutex_lock(&bridge);
    removeFromQueue(city, threadNumber);

    printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [>> %d  >>] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, threadNumber, inQueueB, inCityB);
    if (debugMode == 1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueA);
        printQueue(city);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueA);
    }
    city = 'b';

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bridge);
    sleep(2); // Sleeping for simulating "working" time

    int randomNumber = rand() % 4;

    if (randomNumber % 2 == 0)
    {
        addToQueue(city, threadNumber);
        changeCity2(threadNumber, city);
    }
    else
    {
        runIntoCity(threadNumber, city);
    }
    }
    else if (city == 'b')
    {
    while (queueInB[0] != threadNumber); // Oczekiwanie dopoki samochod nie jest 1szy w kolejce      

    pthread_mutex_lock(&bridge);


    removeFromQueue(city, threadNumber);


    printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [<< %d  <<] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, threadNumber, inQueueB, inCityB);
    if (debugMode == 1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueB);
        printQueue(city);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueB);
    }
    city = 'a';


    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bridge);
    sleep(2);

    int randomNumber = rand() % 4;

    if (randomNumber % 2 == 0)
    {
        addToQueue(city, threadNumber);
        changeCity2(threadNumber, city);
    }
    else
    {
        runIntoCity(threadNumber, city);
    }
    }
}

void runIntoCity(int threadNumber, char city)
{

    if (city == 'a')
    {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cityA);
    inCityA++;
    printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [ BLANK  ] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, inQueueB, inCityB);
    if (debugMode == 1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueA);
        printQueue(city);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueA);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cityA);

    sleep(3);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cityA);
    inCityA--;
    printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [ BLANK  ] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, inQueueB, inCityB);

    if (debugMode == 1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueA);
        printQueue(city);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueA);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cityA);
    }
    else
    {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cityB);
    inCityB++;
    printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [ BLANK  ] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, inQueueB, inCityB);

    if (debugMode == 1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueB);
        printQueue(city);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueB);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cityB);

    sleep(3);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cityB);
    inCityB--;
    printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [ BLANK  ] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, inQueueB, inCityB);
    if (debugMode == 1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueB);
        printQueue(city);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueB);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cityB);
    }


    addToQueue(city, threadNumber);
    changeCity2(threadNumber, city);
}

void removeFromQueue(char city, int threadNumber) // Removing car from queue if its 1st in queue
{
    if (city == 'a') // Car being removed from queue of city A
    {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queueA);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&countOfQueueA);
    if (queueInA[0] == threadNumber)
    {

        inQueueA--;

        int i = 1; 
        while (queueInA[i] != 0)
        {
            queueInA[i - 1] = queueInA[i];
            i++;
        }
        queueInA[i - 1] = 0;
        printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [ BLANK  ] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, inQueueB, inCityB);


        if (debugMode == 1)
        {

            printQueue(city);
        }
    }
    else printf("Car is not first in queue. Error!");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueA);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&countOfQueueA);
    }
    else if (city == 'b') 
    {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queueB);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&countOfQueueB);
    if (queueInB[0] == threadNumber)
    {

        inQueueB--;

        int i = 1;
        while (queueInB[i] != 0)
        {
            queueInB[i - 1] = queueInB[i];
            i++;
        }
        queueInB[i - 1] = 0;

        printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [ BLANK  ] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, inQueueB, inCityB);

        if (debugMode == 1)
        {
            printQueue(city);
        }
    }
    else printf("Samochod nie jest pierwszy w kolejce. BLAD W KODZIE!");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueB);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&countOfQueueB);
    }
}



void changeCity(int threadNumber, char city)
{
    if (city == 'a')
    {
    while (queueInA[0] != threadNumber); // Waiting until car is ready to change city - it's first in queue

    pthread_mutex_lock(&bridge);
    removeFromQueue(city, threadNumber);



    printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [>> %d  >>] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, threadNumber, inQueueB, inCityB);
    if (debugMode == 1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueA);
        printQueue(city);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueA);
    }
    city = 'b';


    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bridge);
    sleep(2);

    int randomNumber = rand() % 4;

    if (randomNumber % 2 == 0)
    {
        addToQueue(city, threadNumber);
        changeCity2(threadNumber, city);
    }
    else
    {
        runIntoCity(threadNumber, city);
    }
    }
    else if (city == 'b')
    {
    while (queueInB[0] != threadNumber); // Waiting until car is ready to change city - it's first in queue  

    pthread_mutex_lock(&bridge);


    removeFromQueue(city, threadNumber);


    printf("\nA-%d %d>>> [<< %d  <<] <<<%d %d-B", inCityA, inQueueA, threadNumber, inQueueB, inCityB);
    if (debugMode == 1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueB);

        printQueue(city);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueB);
    }
    city = 'a';


    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bridge);
    sleep(2);

    int randomNumber = rand() % 4;

    if (randomNumber % 2 == 0)
    {
        addToQueue(city, threadNumber);
        changeCity2(threadNumber, city);
    }
    else
    {
        runIntoCity(threadNumber, city);
    }
    }
}

char cityDraw() // Being used at start of thread to attach threads to cities
{
    int randomNumber = rand() % 100;
    int randomNumber2 = rand() % randomNumber;

    if (randomNumber2 % 2 == 0)
    {
    return 'a';
    }
    else
    {
    return 'b';
    }
}

void *threadInitiate(int threadNumber)
{
    char city = cityDraw();
    addToQueue(city, threadNumber);
    while (inQueueA + inQueueB < numberOfCars); // Waiting for all threads to get run by pthread_create
    changeCity(threadNumber, city);
}

void createThreads()
{
    pthread_t car[numberOfCars];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfCars; i++)
    {
    int wynik = pthread_create(&car[i], NULL, &threadInitiate, (void *)i + 1); //!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    if (wynik != 0) printf("Pthread_create failed\n");
    else createdThreads++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfCars; i++)
    {
    pthread_join(car[i], NULL);
    }
}

void initiateQueues() // Making every elem. of queues became 0. Just to be sure. Thread numbers are starting from number 1.
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<numberOfCars; i++)
    {
    queueInA[i] = 0;
    queueInB[i] = 0;
    }
}

int checkNumberOfCars(char *arg) // Parsing and converting to int,  numer of cars from parameter
{
    int argSize = 1;
    while (arg[argSize] != '\0')
    {
    argSize++;
    }

    char temp[argSize];
    int indArg = 1;
    int indTemp = 0;
    for (indArg = 1; indArg<argSize; indArg++)
    {
    temp[indTemp] = arg[indArg];
    indTemp++;
    }
    temp[indTemp] = '\0';

    int ls = atoi(temp);
    return ls;
}

int debugCheck(int argc, char **argv) // Checking if -debug parameter is given
{
    if (argc>2)
    {
    if (strcmp(argv[2], "-debug") == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    numberOfCars = checkNumberOfCars(argv[1]);
    printf("\nNumber of cars from param = %d", numberOfCars);
    debugMode = debugCheck(argc, argv);
    if (debugMode == 1) printf("\nDebugMode is ON - writing queues status on every change");
    int queueArrayA[numberOfCars];
    int queueArrayB[numberOfCars];
    queueInA = queueArrayA;
    queueInB = queueArrayB;
    initiateQueues();

    pthread_mutex_init(&bridge, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&queueA, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&queueB, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&cityA, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&cityB, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&countOfQueueA, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&countOfQueueB, NULL);

    createThreads();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question or problem?  This is very broad.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry.  I think threads doesnt work synchronyzed, for example I runned program with 8 threads and had thread with number 34 in queue. No idea why, and it happened after I "fixed" code. Won't go back cause it haven't work either.

Comment: Sorry, I really like diversity, but reading code with non-English variable and function names is just something that you should not expect the StackOverflow community to do.

Comment: Changed to english version. Sorry but I'm barely thinking. I guess something is wrong with mutexes because some of threads are missing after few secs of working.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even compile.  Please provide a [minimal, compilable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Do you compile it with linking pthread lib? Like: gcc -o name source.c -lpthread Everything was fine when I had only queues and switching cities. After adding runIntoCity() idea it wasn't working and I tryed to figure it out.

Comment: @kondzio14 - Yes I linked with pthread.  The errors I'm getting are basic C errors like conflicting/incompatible types, control reaching the end of a non-void function, invalid integer-to-pointer typecasts, etc.  See http://ideone.com/rJnFyZ for an example.

Comment: @bta Kinda funny because I don't have warnings/errors like this. I guess like Krzysztof_Kosiński said it's better to rewrite code than looking for "bad code" and I'm working now on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an assignment for a course in concurrent programming. There is a multitude of problems with this code, and I don't think it's worth trying to find the error because you will get no points for this and everything has to be rewritten anyway. Here are the issues roughly in order of importance.

1. What is the purpose of the queues? The car threads should just all try to lock the mutex. There is no need for a queue in your program - a queue of threads waiting for the mutex is managed behind the scenes by the operating system. The car threads should probably do something like this:

   ```
   pthread_mutex_lock(&bridge);
   // remove car from city of origin
   // no need for mutex, because only one car can be on the bridge at once,
   // so only the car on the bridge will modify the car count fields in cities
   city[i].cars--;
   sleep(/* some time */);
   // add car to destination city
   city[1-i].cars++;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&bridge);
   sleep(/* some time */);
   ```
2. The car threads will run forever, but they will keep calling more and more functions recursively. This will eventually blow up the stack. Write the car thread function as an explicit infinite loop. No physical computer will allow you have a call graph of infinite depth.
3. Tons of duplicate code. Everything is written twice, once for city 'a' and the second time for city 'b'. Make use of arrays and assign the number 0 to one city and 1 to the other, so that you can do something like `city[1-i].car_count++`.
4. Code that manages the queue data structure (e.g. finds an empty space, removes a car from the queue, and so on) is mixed up with other unrelated code. If you really need those queues, which I doubt, write a `struct car_queue` and operations that add and remove a car, instead of writing queue operations directly in the functions `changeCity2`, `addToQueue` and so on.
5. Unnecessary mutexes. For example, `countofQueueA` and `queueA` should be combined into a single mutex. In fact, probably there should be only three mutexes: for city A, for city B and for the bridge. It could be even done with just one mutex for the bridge.
6. Why are you doing `rand() % 4` and right after that `% 2` with the result? It doesn't make any sense, do `rand() % 2` right away.
7. The double randomization in `cityDraw` is completely pointless and gives you a slightly biased result. For instance, if you get 0 in the first line, you will get either 0, 1 or 2 in the second line, so there will be 2/3 chance that the car will go to city A. If you get 0 in the first line, the car will go to city A regardless of what you get in the second. Just do `rand() % 2`.
8. Never do something like `#define true 1` - this just introduced gratuitous incompatibilities with C++. Instead, use `#include <stdlib.h>` and write `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks :) very useful. Removed queues, rewritten some functions and it works.